# Combining data in pivot table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table by using summary statistics in ArcMap. I have summarized three columns that I would like to sort by the same row data.

Is there any way to combine the values in these columns either in excel or through the table created in ArcMap?

I am currently only able to view each field and its associated data separately after adding all three fields to the column area.